# With orthotics, is there any objective way to know if your feet are being held in the right position?

Tags: orthotics, podiatry, flat-feet-fallen-arches

I've had flat feet for years, but unfortunately, my parents didn't really know that this was an issue until it was pretty much too late to correct it.

Now, as an adult, I've been trying to get back into running again, so I can lose some weight.  Unfortunately, my feet hurt terribly.  I have a Brooks pair of shoes that I know is good.  As well, I've gotten some custom orthotics.

However, the podiatrist I see insists that the orthotics are fine, and that my feet don't need to be pushed anymore into the right position than they already are.  I'm pretty sure he's wrong, but if he's not, I don't want to insist that my inserts be adjusted, only to find out that I was wrong.

I only have feelings as to whether or not my feet are being held in the right position, but these are subjective, and I don't think they're reliable.

Is there any objective way to know for sure if my feet are being held in the healthiest position possible when I walk or run?  Is there some sort of test that exists that my doctor, perhaps, doesn't know about?

Comment: Excellent question at its root.  I'll edit it soon.  Meanwhile, to guide you, I provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any tests you can do, other than subjectively analyzing your gait for stability, joint pressure, and pain.

But I can guide you to your options.

The 3 primary medical professionals who deal with orthotics are

- Orthotics departments associated with orthotists/physiatrists (MD or DO physician with specialties in musculoskeletal conditions)
- Podiatrists (a different type of doctor than any specialty of MD or DO)
- Physical therapists (usually not the ones prescribing but may make recommendations)

For what it's worth, I got mine via the orthotics department of a hospital system that's associated with an MD physiatrist office.